# Arduino-controlled current limiter for lathe

Tags: sensors, motor, current

I'm building a lathe that will be powered by a 3-phase 750w AC motor (4 pole, max unloaded RPM of 1400 RPM). I want to be able to control the RPM using a potentiometer attached to an Arduino mega which I can figure out how to do.

Under load, I'm guessing the motor is going to want to draw more current across each of the phases, the cabling can take the extra current draw but I don't want to damage the motor.

Could I use AnalogueRead (using current transducers) to tell the Arduino to increase the resistance with a servo-potentiometer setup or cut the power momentarily (using transistors on each phase) if the current rose above a certain level? If so, is there any code that would be good to steal/adapt?

Thanks all!